# HTTP POST returns 21201 - No 'To' Number Specified - MS Flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Looking to send an HTTP POST through Microsoft Flow/Power Automate to make a voice call in Twilio.  I feel like I've tried every iteration possible, but keep getting the error 21201:

```
{
  "code": 21201,
  "message": "No 'To' number is specified",
  "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21201",
  "status": 400
}
```

[Screenshot of Power Automate HTTP Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDPJ0.png)

I've seen other vids of people using Azure Functions with C# and it feels like I should be able to do what I need here...like, really close.  But I'm not a dev, so maybe I'm way off.  Would appreciate any direction on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be you are sending a content type of application/json where Twilio requires application/x-www-form-urlencoded

[Creating or Updating Resources with the HTTP POST and PUT Methods](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/your-request-to-twilio#post)

Also found this:

[Custom connector action with x-www-form-urlencoded content-type](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Custom-connector-action-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-content-type/td-p/128691.)